# AVFoundation - What is the best way to re-encode a video file (to add more keyframes)?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I have a mp4 file that doesn't seek accurately, and seeking backwards is slow. I believe it is caused by a heavily compressed encoding.

What is the best way to re-encode this file using AVFoundation so that I can make every frame a key frame?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to set the (max) key frame interval is [`AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideomaxkeyframeintervalkey?language=objc).

> The corresponding value is an instance of `NSNumber`. ***1 means key frames
> only***.

You could apply it to an `AVAssetWriter` object, which might look similar to this:

```
NSDictionary *compProps = @{ AVVideoAverageBitRateKey : @(bitsPerSecond), 
                             AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey : @(30),
                             AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey : @(1) };

_videoInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput alloc] initWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo 
                                          outputSettings:compProps];
```

↳ [AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideomaxkeyframeintervalkey?language=objc)